# Kong fails with: error loading module 'kong.plugins.saml.handler' after migrations up

Tags: ubuntu, kong

After running Kong (v3.2.1) without issue for months, it was prompting me to run 'kong migrations up'.  This I did but on attempting to restart, I get the following in the error log:

```
2023/03/02 08:39:00 [notice] 825679#0: [lua] license_helpers.lua:155: read_license_info(): [license-helpers] could not decode license JSON: No license found
2023/03/02 08:39:00 [info] 825679#0: [lua] licensing.lua:238: update(): [licensing] license type: free
2023/03/02 08:39:00 [notice] 825679#0: [lua] license_helpers.lua:155: read_license_info(): [license-helpers] could not decode license JSON: No license found
2023/03/02 08:39:00 [info] 825679#0: [lua] utils.lua:158: set_region(): set AWS auto-detected region to 'nil' with error msg: unable to detect AWS region, all options failed
2023/03/02 08:39:00 [warn] 825679#0: [kong] [C]:-1 [Penlight 1.13.1] the contents of module 'pl.xml' has been deprecated, please use a more specialized library instead (deprecated after 1.11.0, scheduled for removal in 2.0.0)
2023/03/02 08:39:00 [error] 825679#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/utils.lua:707: error loading module 'kong.plugins.saml.handler':
./saml/utils/xmlcatalog.lua:21: file 'xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml' not found:
    could not recognize @./saml/utils/xmlcatalog.lua as a LuaRocks module
    can't open ./saml/utils/xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: ./saml/utils/xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: No such file or directory
    can't open /usr/share/xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: /usr/share/xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: No such file or directory
    can't open /usr/lib/xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: /usr/lib/xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: No such file or directory
    can't open ./xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: ./xml/xsd/saml-metadata.xml: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    ./saml/utils/xmlcatalog.lua:21: in function 'load'
    ./saml/saml.lua:25: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./saml/handler.lua:22: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x7f97f9e4c3f0
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/utils.lua:698: in function 'load_module_if_exists'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:206: in function 'load_plugin_handler'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:313: in function 'load_plugin'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:365: in function 'load_plugin_schemas'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:705: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/utils.lua:707: in function 'load_module_if_exists'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:206: in function 'load_plugin_handler'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:313: in function 'load_plugin'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:365: in function 'load_plugin_schemas'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:705: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
```

I am running Kong v3.2.1 on Ubuntu jammy.  How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I should add I was starting Kong as a daemon under systemctl.  Kong could start manually but failed under systemctl.  I now discover I have to add User/Group=root under the [Service] section to obviate the SAML complaint whereas this was not needed before.